Python, Django. Ошибка при дебаге "attempted relative import with no known parent package"
Пишу проект на Django.
Структура проекта
C:\Dev\APD_project\apd_zip\apd_zip_app
Виртуальное окружение активировано.
Приложение apd_zip_app зарегистрировано в settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apd_zip_app.apps.ApdZipAppConfig', 

При попытке дебага файла C:\Dev\APD_project\apd_zip\apd_zip_app\views.py получаю ошибку на импорте модели from .models import Items_ZIP:

"Exception has occurred: ImportError attempted relative import with no
known parent package   File
"C:\Dev\APD_project\apd_zip\apd_zip_app\views.py", line 5, in 
from .models import Items_ZIP ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Если меняю импорт на from apd_zip_app.models import Items_ZIP
то получаю ошибку, что приложение не зарегистрировано:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named
'apd_zip_app'   File
"C:\Dev\APD_project\apd_zip\apd_zip_app\views.py", line 5, in 
from apd_zip_app.models import Items_ZIP ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apd_zip_app'

Сам проект работает, но в дебаг войти не могу...
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить ошибку?

Попробуйте оформить так:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'apd_zip_app',
]

джанговые приложения регистрировать первыми (при необходимости в них).

Добрый день! Спасибо за помощь! Вчера решил проблему. Если кто столкнется с проблемой. Надо поправить launch.json и дебаг начинает работать. Ссылку не даю, гуглится легко "How To Debug a Django Application in VS CODE (Visual Studio Code)".

Для того, чтобы дебаг заработал надо поправить launch.json согласно проекту. Информация легко находится по запросу "How To Debug a Django Application in VS CODE (Visual Studio Code)".
